# Where should I ask my question about ISP networks?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, specific-question

I tried asking the following in networking, but it does not seem to fit the topics. Maybe there is a better place to ask?

---

I have a pretty general question about how networks work on [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) (Internet service provider) level.

> For example, you live in London and there are a lot of providers for Internet connection, one of which Vodafone, and the other is O2. Both providers have a 50 Mbit/s plan, but the O2 provider has better connectivity to eastern /Asian websites, while Vodafone has more latency and is very slow on lot of them.
>   This is just an example, not a real case. Even if both providers have a local fiber network, international connectivity will be ways better on some than others.
>
> I was wondering what might cause this?

Comment: You probably better ask that at this site specific meta.

Comment: I guess the tricky thing here is unless you had a lot of knowledge about how isp transit agreements are, this would be impossible to answer